# "Scalp a Ticket" vs "Resell a Ticket"

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

The noun "[Scalp](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scalp)" means (mainly):

> 1. The skin covering the head, excluding the face: 'hair tonics will improve the condition of your hair and scalp'
>
> 1.1 [historical] The scalp with the hair belonging to it, cut or torn away from an enemy’s head as *a battle trophy*, *a former practice
>       among American Indians*.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

If you look at the definition of "[ticket resale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_resale)" in [Wikipedia], it could be a common thing for any sports, concerts, etc. in any country.

1. I understand what "to scalp tickets" means, but I don't understand how "to scalp" has evolved to mean "to resell".
2. Does "to scalp" have a stronger connotation of "illegality" than "to resell"?
3. According to [Oxford Online Dictionary], it seems that "to scalp" is mainly used in North America. What would be its counterpart in BrE?

> *North American informal* Resell (shares or tickets) at a large or quick profit: tickets were scalped for forty times their face value

I could get the below Ngram Viewer for AmE, but couldn't find any usage in [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scalp+tickets%2Cresell+tickets&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=).

[image]

Comment: Scalping is generally reselling tickets *way* above original cost due to economic scarcity. I suspect it feels to the buyer as if they've just been scalped in the old native American sense of the word. And should we really be calling them American Indians just because Columbus couldn't navigate his way to the toilet? :-)

Comment: I believe the etymology of "scalping a ticket" comes from the fact that being scalped was highly unpleasant and painful. What differentiates "reselling a ticket" from "scalping a ticket" is the fact that "scalping" implies a high markup. Purchasing a ticket from a scalper is apt to be a unpleasant and a pain in the wallet for the purchaser. "Reselling" implies less, if any, markup. In some locales "scalping" is defined by the degree of markup, and is considered a crime. I'm not certain of the BrE equivalent.

Comment: @Misneac Thank you for your comment. I also understood that way, but "scalp + ticket" doesn't sound right. I don't know why.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thank you for your comment. Regarding the word, it is not my call. :)

Comment: In the barber-shop sense, it`s taking a little off the top :)

Comment: @paxdiablo: I'm not an native speaker and also not that good in english, so maybe I'm just missing something by reading your comment, but for me it sounds like your comment expresses that india is worlds toilet. Is this just a mistake of you or am I just as allready said missing something and, one generally couldn't even missunderstand your comment in the way I did?

Comment: @Zaibis - You're misunderstanding. The comment is intended to be saying that Columbus was very bad at navigating, by formulating the statement in the form of "Columbus couldn't navigate his way to the [obvious location that is well-known or easily found]." Most people know where the toilet is, and if they don't know specifically, they can make an educated guess as to where they can find it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: I'm not trying to blame for this, just to clarify. So there is no way of it could express in this way an equation in the way I understood it? thanks for response.

Comment: "Ticket scalpers" in AmE are "[ticket touts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tout)" in BrE

Comment: @Zaibis That is correct. I understand your misunderstanding: You interpreted the metaphor not literally, but in a different way than the usual  interpretation would be. Your interpretation was that paxdiablo was specifically referring to Columbus navigating to India and substituting "toilet" for India. This is not an interpretation a native speaker would make, I wouldn't worry about it. In reality it was a snide remark about Columbus' *general* navigation skills, not referring to India specifically. I.e. Columbus couldn't even find the nearest bathroom, let alone navigate a ship *anywhere*.

Comment: @Zaibis You might be interested in http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29669/what-does-way-out-of-a-paper-bag-mean

Comment: @Zaibis, apologies, though Roddy/Jason have already explained (and I've only just woken up). One of the problems of international forums is that idioms don't always translate well. The original one I heard was as a youngster when discussing fighting ability (in rougher days than today): "He couldn't punch his way out of a wet paper bag", meaning the punches were barely adequate. I meant *no* disrespect to India (or any other group of people) with my comment.

Comment: @paxdiablo I demand an answer to this question. :)

Comment: @Henry Would you care to elaborate on your comment with an answer? It would be interesting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***[To scalp](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=scalp&searchmode=none)*** carries an informal, possibly illegal (unauthorised)  ,  connotation that *resell* does not:

> - (Informal.)
>     to resell (tickets, merchandise, etc.) at higher than the official rates.

Thus usage is from the late 19th century from a practice that became popular in the U.S. with long distance train tickets:

[Scalp](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=scalp&searchmode=none): (Etymonline)

> - ***Meaning "person who re-sells tickets at unauthorized prices for a profit," 1869, American English;earliest reference is to theater tickets, but often used late 19c. of brokers who sold unused portions of railway tickets.***
>
>   - *[Railways charged less per mile for longer-distance tickets; therefore someone travelling from New York to Chicago could buy a ticket all the way to San Francisco, get out at Chicago and sell it to a scalper, and come away with more money than if he had simply bought a ticket to Chicago; the Chicago scalper would hold the ticket till he found someone looking for a ticket to San Francisco, then sell it to him at a slight advance, but for less than the official price.]*
> - ***Perhaps from scalp (v.); scalper was a generic term for "con man, cheater" in late 19c. Or perhaps the connecting sense is the bounty offered for scalps of certain destructive animals*** (attested in New England from 1703) and sometimes Indians (i.e., having only part of something, but still getting paid). Some, though, see a connection rather to scalpel, the surgical instrument.

***[Scalping](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/scalping.asp) in finance:***

> - A trading strategy that attempts to make many profits on small price changes. Traders who implement this strategy will place anywhere from 10 to a couple hundred trades in a single day in the belief that small moves in stock price are easier to catch than large ones.
> - Traders who implement this strategy are known as scalpers. The main goal is to buy (or sell) a number of shares at the bid (or ask) price and then quickly sell them a few cents higher (or lower) for a profit. Many small profits can easily compound into large gains if a strict exit strategy is used to prevent large losses.

(Investment.com)

Comment: Etymonline defintion you quoted is for the noun "scalper" not "scalp" as your answer suggest at this moment.

Answer (score 3):

"Scalp", as a verb, is a common (though less so over time (*)) usage in the US.  In general (when not meaning to physically relieve someone of their hair, if only in a barber shop) it means to sell something at an exorbitant price (or buy something at an artificially low price), under some situation where the other party has little choice.  (Eg, "We got scalped on that hotel room, but it was the only one left in town."  Or, "I got scalped selling the house, but I needed the money.")

The reference clearly is to the historical practice of some Native American tribes to take the scalps of their fallen adversaries as battle trophies.  As I understand it, this was usually done when the victim was dead, but occasionally while still alive, and would have been excruciatingly painful to the live victim.

(*) Likely "scalp" in the sense of reselling tickets for profit will continue to be used, but it's use for the more general case seems to be diminishing.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is only to the question

> Does "to scalp" have a stronger connotation of "illegality" than "to
>   resell"?

It's not just a stronger connotation, but rather that the illegality is the defining difference between scalping and reselling.

Reselling generally is perfectly legal. If it wasn't, there would be no supermarkets, no Craigslist, no eBay.

For certain goods - primarily for tickets - there are restrictions on who can resell, and for what price. The reasoning is that unlike most types of goods, tickets for events are both limited in number (in the relevant cases, dramatically less than the demand), and time sensitive. Unlike eggs or purses or skis, with tickets, once they are gone, they are gone, and once the event has passed, they have no value.

When a few people (the scalpers) buy large numbers of such tickets, they further exacerbate the scarcity of the tickets, thus driving up prices further.

Basically, scalping more similar to stock market manipulation, or Enron's activities, than to reselling.